# Access VBA textbox matrix

Tags: vba, ms-access, textbox, isnullorempty

I would like to insert 1-24 rows into a DB after some VBA precheck. I made an MSAccess form with textbox grid, and name them like this:
[image]

I would like only insert the rows with filled "Name". Code:

```
For i = 1 To 24
namegrid = "Name" & i & ".Value"
If IsNull(namegrid) Then
 Else
    InsertProduct = "Insert INTO Products (Productname, QTY, IncomingPrice, Desc) VALUES (Name" & i    & ".value, QTY" & i & ".value, Price" & i & ".value, Desc" & i & ")"
    DoCmd.RunSQL InsertProduct
 End If Next i
```

The If *IsNull(namegrid)* is not working properly (I think is check the variant instead of the referenced Textbox).

How to do it correctly? (cheking the lenght also tried with no success)
Maybe I have wrong conception...

Comment: Try `namegrid = Me.Controls("Name" & i).Value`

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!